# $.getJSON doesn't work for all .json files on same domain in IE11

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-11

I'm building a frontend only web app and at some point i do this:

```
$.when(

// #1
$.getJSON(this.apiURL + 'operationareas?loc=' + this.location_name + '&oauth_consumer_key=' + this.apiKey + '&format=json&callback=?', function (data) {
    $.each(data.placemarks, function (idx, node) {
        self.mapDB['areas'][idx] = node;
    });
}),

// #2
$.getJSON('data/'+self.location + '.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.zones, function (idx, node) {
        self.mapDB['zones'][idx] = node;
    });
}),

// #3
$.getJSON(this.apiURL + 'vehicles?loc=' + this.location_name + '&oauth_consumer_key=' + this.apiKey + '&format=json&callback=?', function (data) {
    $.each(data.placemarks, function (idx, node) {
        self.mapDB['cars'][idx] = node;
    });
})
).done(...)
```

I load 3 JSON Files at a time, 2 from an API and one from the same server. Works fine in all browsers except IE11 (haven't testet lower).

In IE11, #1 and #3 (the API calls) work fine. The local request (#2) however returns a "SyntaxError: Invalid Character" in the `jqXHR`-object and "parseError" as `textStatus`. The weird thing is, this happens only to like half of the JSONs i'm trying to get. The rest works fine. All files are validated by jsonlint.com.

Any ideas what could cause this behavior?

Comment: Check that the generated url for the `$.getJSON()` call is correct, and corresponds to a `.json` file that actually exists?

Comment: Which version of jquery lib are u using ?

Comment: we used 1.11. Error is fixed. It was umlauts (ä,ö,ü) that where shown as htmlentities due to editing errors and switching between UTF8 and ANCII by a third party. Thank you for your help, time and effort!

Comment: @Sumit: thats a good thing, now lets close this question.

Answer (score 1):

**This issue is a bug reported to Jquery 4 months ago.**

Possible wrong implementation of local ajax request on Internet Explorer browser by microsoft.

anyway its been fixed now by Jquery community :)

Complete details of the Bug and the fix is [HERE](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14475)

Happy Coding :)